# python string formatting from list with arbitrary item

Tags: python, list, string-formatting

I want to do a string formatting with a list as showed below:

(`pseudocode`)

```
down_url = [url1, url2, ..., urln]    
url = "download: %s" % down_url
```

Yes, the list `down_url` has arbitrary items, and I want to get all the items from it. The result I want is:

```
download: url1, url2, ..., urln
```

I hope you can understand what I have expressed. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print("download: " + ", ".join(down_url))
```

**Explanation:**

[`"sep".join(iterable)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.join#str.join) joins all elements in `iterable` using the separator `sep` and returns a string. So for example:

```
>>> "".join(("a", "b", "c"))
'abc'
>>> ", ".join(("a", "b", "c"))
'a, b, c'
```

In case your iterable contains elements other than strings, you can force them to be mapped into strings before passing them to the `.join()` method:

```
>>> ", ".join(map(str, ("a", 2, "c")))
'a, 2, c'
```